# Why php artisan migrate doesn't work with Docker?

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I use docker and  do `laravel new blog`, after that I do `php artisan migrate` and get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = books and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

So what I do wrong?

This is my docker-compose.yml, I use mariaDB and adminer instead phpmyadmin

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    build: ./web
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
      - ./web/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
    volumes:
      - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080

  composer:
    image: composer:1.6
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    command: composer install
```

Comment: Hi @Evgeny, you will have to provide more information. What does your Docker setup look like? Do you have database container running?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I put information about docker settings above

Comment: What do any DB_HOST entries in your .env look like? Have you done any customization to config/db.php? If so, what was changed? 

It seems like it might be failing to resolve the db host.

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper db settings in .env file: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=books
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=12345.
And I didn't change config/database.php

Answer (score 3):

In your db container add :

```
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
  MYSQL_DATABASE: databaseName
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
  SERVICE_TAGS: dev
  SERVICE_NAME: mysql
```

Then go inside your container using:

```
docker exec -it web bash
```

This will open the console of your laravel container and in there run

```
php artisan optimize
```

To make use of your env file variables.

A step you must take before that is to create your database inside docker using mysql workbench or a similar tool.

You can connect using below credentials:

```
Host: 0.0.0.0
username : root
password : secret
port : 3306
```

And then create an empty database using the name of your database you are using in your env file & in the `docker_compose`

Your laravel env file should be changed a bit so it loads the mysql container.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db //This is the container name you use
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDatabaseName
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

***Comment Answer:***

The error in your comment means that you are missing gd extension. Inside your docker file use the below lines:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: After `php artisan migrate` I got another error `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/gd2 (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/gd2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/gd2.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/gd2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))`, so at first, I will solve this problem and I will continue trying your suggestion, thank you for the answer

Comment: @EvgenyMusonov You should make a separate question for that

Comment: Updated my answer, to answer also your comment but this is indeed a separate question.